# Repository With UnitOfWork pattern for database in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, unit-of-work

Today I would like to implement repository pattern + unit of work pattern for database connection. Is my code bellow correct?? Because this is my first implementation unit of work for database connection.

First repository:

```
public class NotesRepository : INotesRepository
{
    private DatabaseContext context;

    public NotesRepository(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<Notes> GetAllNotes()
    {
        return (from x in context.Notes
                select x);
    }
}
```

Second repository:

```
public class CommentsRepository : ICommentsRepository
{
    private DatabaseContext context;

    public CommentsRepository(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<Comments> GetAllComments()
    {
        return (from x in context.Comments
                select x);
    }
}
```

Unit of work class for database connection:

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    private DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext();
    private INotesRepository notesRepository;
    private ICommentsRepository commentsRepository;

    public INotesRepository NotesRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.notesRepository == null)
            {
                this.notesRepository = new NotesRepository(context);
            }
            return notesRepository;
        }
    }

    public ICommentsRepository CommentsRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.commentsRepository == null)
            {
                this.commentsRepository = new CommentsRepository(context);
            }
            return commentsRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

And controller in which I can use many repositories with single database connection:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();        

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var a = unitOfWork.NotesRepository.GetAllNotes();
            var b = unitOfWork.CommentsRepository.GetAllComments();

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is very right :)

**But I advice you to use IUnitOfWork interface and pass the DatabaseContext instance in the constructor.**

**Another thing to do is to make a SaveChanges method in the UnitOfWork to commit the data to the database.**